# cordova/phonegap File plugin on android 4.2

Tags: android, cordova, file-upload, phonegap-plugins

i am using [File plugin](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html) to upload files to my cordova app, and its working fine on android 4.4.

when trying to open the file selector on android 4.2 (galaxy s3) or android 4.1 (asus tablet), nothing happens.

here is the code:

```
 window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT,0,function(obj){console.log(obj)},function(error){console.log(error);});
```

i also noticed , i don't get an error, and the success log is:

> {
>   name: "persistent",
>   root: {
>   filesystem: Object,
>   fullPath: "/",
>   isDirectory: true,
>   isFile: false,
>   name: "",
>   nativeURL: "file:///data/data/com.blox.alpha/files/files/",
>   **proto**: Object
>   },
>   **proto**: Object
>   }

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there have been changes on the storage section on KitKat (4.4), as explained here: http://www.androidcentral.com/kitkat-sdcard-changes

What version of Cordova/Android SDK are you using to compile and run? This is working for me on Android 4.2.1 (tablet) and 4.4 (phone), using Cordova 3.7.1.

On deviceready event:

```
function fsSuccess(fileSystem)
{
    alert(fileSystem.root.toURL());
}

function fsFail(event)
{
    alert(evt.target.error.code);
}

window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, fsSuccess, fsFail);
```

On success, you should get an alert with the root absolute url that you should prepend on every filename you have to read/write.

In my case: **file:///storage/emulated/0/** mydir/myfile.txt